# Subset based on duplicated ID and if value is a duplicate of value in another column of the subsequent row

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, data.table, subset

I have a data.frame `df` looking something like this

```
ID      VALUE_1   VALUE_2   VALUE_3
Pete      55        52         53
Amber     23        33         47
Amber     47        25         69
Bob       34        25         52
Bob       52        78         93
Bob       93        11         83
Alfie     24        75         52
Alfie     13        64         32
```

I am interested in subsetting retaining only the duplicates in terms of names and if `VALUE_3` is equal/duplicate to the subsequent `VALUE_1` yielding the result output:

```
ID      VALUE_1   VALUE_2   VALUE_3
Amber     23        33         47
Amber     47        25         69
Bob       34        25         52
Bob       52        78         93
Bob       93        11         83
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea using `tidyverse`. We group by `ID` and remove all groups with only 1 observation. We then create a logical column with the values_3 that equal with the next value_1. We then use `fill` to fill the statement, and use that variable to filter

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 filter(n() > 1) %>% 
 mutate(new = VALUE_3 == lead(VALUE_1)) %>% 
 fill(new) %>% 
 filter(new) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 select(-new)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 4
>   ID    VALUE_1 VALUE_2 VALUE_3
>   <fct>   <int>   <int>   <int>
> 1 Amber      23      33      47
> 2 Amber      47      25      69
> 3 Bob        34      25      52
> 4 Bob        52      78      93
> 5 Bob        93      11      83
> ```

A couple of `data.table` ways for achieving the above(compliments of @akrun and @Frank)

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, .SD[cummax(.N >1 & VALUE_3 == shift(VALUE_1, type = 'lead', fill = last(VALUE_1))) > 0], ID]  -- #akrun

w = DF[VALUE_1 == shift(VALUE_3) & ID == shift(ID), which = TRUE] 
DF[unique(sort(c(w, w-1)))] -- #Frank
```

Comment: May be this would work as well `library(data.table);setDT(df)[, .SD[cummax(.N >1 & VALUE_3 == shift(VALUE_1, type = 'lead', fill = last(VALUE_1))) > 0], ID]`

Comment: Or without any group-by operations: `w = DF[VALUE_1 == shift(VALUE_3) & ID == shift(ID), which = TRUE]; DF[unique(sort(c(w, w-1)))]`